# Why do lm and biglm in R give different p-values for the same data?

Tags: r, regression, p-value, linear-model

Here is a small example:

```
MyDf<-data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4), y=c(1.2, .7, -.5, -3))
```

Now with the`base::lm`:

```
> lm(y~x, data=MyDf) %>% summary

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = MyDf)

Residuals:
    1     2     3     4 
-0.47  0.41  0.59 -0.53 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)   3.0500     0.8738   3.491   0.0732 .
x            -1.3800     0.3191  -4.325   0.0495 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.7134 on 2 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9034,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8551 
F-statistic: 18.71 on 1 and 2 DF,  p-value: 0.04952
```

Now, try the same thing with `biglm` from the `biglm` package:

```
XX<-biglm(y~x, data=MyDf) 
print(summary(XX), digits=5)

Large data regression model: biglm(y ~ x, data = MyDf)
Sample size =  4 
             Coef     (95%      CI)      SE       p
(Intercept)  3.05  1.30243  4.79757 0.87378 0.00048
x           -1.38 -2.01812 -0.74188 0.31906 0.00002
```

Note that we need the `print` and `digits` to see the p-value. The coefficients and standard errors are the same, but the p-values are very different. Why is this so?

Comment: +1 Hint: compare `pt(-3.491, 2)*2` to `pnorm(-3.491)*2`, for example.

Comment: @whuber Thanks. So essentially it is a t-distribution vs. normal distribution issue. Is the idea that the normal distribution makes more sense for large data sets that are typical of biglm?

Comment: I think idea is that normal is not not that different from t with high $\nu$ value. Try example from first comment, but change pt(-3.491, 2)*2 to pt(-3.491, 2e3)*2.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**To see which p-values are correct** (if either), let's repeat the calculation for simulated data in which the null hypothesis is true.  In the present setting, the calculation is a least-squares fit to (x,y) data and the null hypothesis is that the slope is zero.  In the question there are four x values 1,2,3,4 and the estimated error is around 0.7, so let's incorporate that in the simulation.

Here is the setup, written to be understandable to everyone, even those unfamiliar with `R`.

```
beta <- c(intercept=0, slope=0)
sigma <- 0.7
x <- 1:4
y.expected <-  beta["intercept"] + beta["slope"] * x
```

The simulation generates independent errors, adds them to `y.expected`, invokes `lm` to make the fit, and `summary` to compute the p-values.  Although this is inefficient, *it is testing the actual code that was used.*  We can still do thousands of iterations in a second:

```
n.sim <- 1e3
set.seed(17)
data.simulated <- matrix(rnorm(n.sim*length(y.expected), y.expected, sigma), ncol=n.sim)
slope.p.value <- function(e) coef(summary(lm(y.expected + e ~ x)))["x", "Pr(>|t|)"]
p.values <- apply(data.simulated, 2, slope.p.value)
```

**Correctly computed p-values will act like uniform random numbers between $0$ and $1$** when the null hypothesis is true.  A histogram of these p-values will allow us to check this visually--does it look roughly horizontal--and a chi-squared test of uniformity will permit a more formal evaluation.  Here's the histogram:

```
h <- hist(p.values, breaks=seq(0, 1, length.out=20))
```

[image: Figure]

and, for those who might imagine this isn't sufficiently uniform, here's the chi-squared test:

```
chisq.test(h$counts)
```

> X-squared = 13.042, df = 18, p-value = 0.7891

The large p-value in this test shows these results are consistent with the expected uniformity.  In other words, **`lm` is correct.**

Where, then, do the differences in p-values come from?  Let's check the likely formulas that might be invoked to compute a p-value.  In any case the test statistic will be

$$|t| = \left| \frac{\hat\beta - 0}{\operatorname{se}(\hat \beta)}\right|,$$

equal to the discrepancy between the estimated coefficient $\hat \beta$ and the hypothesized (and correct value) $\beta = 0$, expressed as a multiple of the standard error of the coefficient estimate.  In the question these values are

$$|t| = \left|\frac{3.05}{0.87378 }\right| = 3.491$$

for the intercept estimate and

$$|t| = \left|\frac{-1.38 }{ 0.31906 }\right| = 4.321$$

for the slope estimate.  Ordinarily these would be compared to the Student $t$ distribution whose degrees of freedom parameter is $4$ (the amount of data) minus $2$ (the number of estimated coefficients).  Let's calculate it for the intercept:

```
pt(-abs(3.05/0.87378), 4-2) * 2

[1] 0.0732
```

(This calculation multiplies the left-tailed Student $t$ probability by $2$ because this is a test of $H_0:\beta=0$ against the two-sided alternative $H_A:\beta \ne 0$.)  *It agrees with the `lm` output.*

An alternative calculation would use the standard Normal distribution to approximate the Student $t$ distribution.  Let's see what it produces:

```
pnorm(-abs(3.05/0.87378)) * 2

[1] 0.000482
```

Sure enough: `biglm` assumes the null distribution of the $t$ statistic is standard Normal.  How much of an error is this?  Re-running the preceding simulation using `biglm` in place of `lm` gives this histogram of p-values:

[image: Figure 2]

Almost 18% of these p-values are less than $0.05$, a standard threshold of "significance."  That's an enormous error.

---

**Some lessons we can learn from this little investigation are:**

1. Do not use approximations derived from asymptotic analyses (like the standard Normal distribution) with small datasets.
2. Know your software.

Comment: Good answer (+1). But you are taking $n = 4$ which is not really big data... I think the author of the package disregarded the small $n$ case in favour of the typical big data case. Worth to point it out, however, in the help to avoid these confusions.